# what exactly is the issue with Nvidia GeForce FX 5200 and unity?

Tags: unity, nvidia

I am using the [Nvidia GeForce FX 5200](http://www.nvidia.com/page/fx_5200.html) and forced Unity on startup.

Everything works fine including glxgears, however I do not have any visible icons in launcher.  I know this has been [reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/762478).

According to my logs it seems to be a g_dbus error.  If the card was not blacklisted I believe D-bus would be finding the icons.  I would like to know exactly what the issue is with this specific card.

Comment: `however I do not have any visible icons in launcher` << That, probably. When I force Unity to start (my card is blacklisted as well) everything simply works... Appart from visual effects stuttering and going **really** slow, and my graphic card overheating.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) + it is abandoned, so voting to close it off. Cheers!